# "El hecho de que" + subjuntivo

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Según un artículo el uso del subjuntivo después de la frase *el hecho de que* significa que "the speaker expresses a subjective, emotional or evaluative reaction". No veo ningún matiz emocional en esta oración:

> Era un colegio caro, y **el hecho de que ella estudiara allí** era solo un indicio de la situación económica de la familia.

¿Me podríais explicarlo por favor?

Comment: *Si se estudia en Colegio X, entonces la familia está adinerada* -- esta secuencia lógica requiere una "evaluative reaction."  Es decir, es un poco *judgmental*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El subjuntivo tiene muchos [usos distintos](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html). Aparte de "expresar emoción o sentimiento" sirve también para "Para expresar una opinión con expresiones impersonales como:"

> Es necesario que nosotros **sepamos** los verbos en el pasado.
>
> Es una lástima que Julián no **pueda** venir a la fiesta.
>
> Es normal que tú te **sientas** triste por la noticia.

Que es el uso que se hace en este caso

> Era solo un indicio de la situación económica de la familia el hecho de que ella **estudiara** allí
>
> Es solo un indicio de la situación económica de la familia el hecho de que ella **estudie** allí <sub>Cambiado a presenta por si facilita entender el ejemplo</sub>

Está expresando una opinión mediante el uso impersonal (como si fuera casi objetivo). "Si ella estudia allí, es que la familia tiene dinero". Es una opinión o deducción. El uso impersonal parece que le concede cierta "validez universal", como si fuera tan obvio que todo el mundo llegaría a la misma conclusión, pero no tiene porqué ser así para ninguno de los ejemplos propuestos (otras personas pueden llegar a una deducción distinta).

Comment: No creo que el mero hecho de ser impersonal nos diga todo, porque otras impersonales como «es verdad que...» no admiten el subjuntivo. Para mí, lo que más obliga el subjuntivo es que que estudia ella no es la totalidad de explanación. «El hecho de que tiene esta casa nos permite decir que es rico» (veo el subjuntivo aquí más difícil), frente a «El hecho de que sea de familia rica no significa que sea bien educado (aquí, el hecho no tiene nada que ver, por lo que para mí el subjuntivo es casi requisito). En la frase del OP, queda relevante a medias, por lo que me parece mejor subjuntivo, ¿no?