# Subjuntivo - "Habían quedado atrás las casualidades de que ella entrara mientras él se bañaba"

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

¿Me podríais por favor explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase? No entiendo qué hay en la frase principal que provoca el uso del subjuntivo en la subordinada.

> Habían quedado atrás las casualidades **de que ella entrara** mientras él
>   se bañaba.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es difícil responder, pero creo que se trata de caso parecido al de las expresiones del tipo *«el hecho de que»* (sobre las cuales, coincidentemente, [hiciste una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/el-hecho-de-que-subjuntivo)). En una [fuente](https://www.espanolavanzado.com/25-gramatica/297-que-el-hecho-de-que) leemos que *el hecho de que...*

> Suele ir seguido del verbo en subjuntivo porque **no está informando al
>   oyente de nada nuevo**, sino haciendo un comentario sobre una
>   información consabida; cuando la expresión encabeza la frase, casi
>   siempre va seguida del subjuntivo por este motivo. En cambio, cuando
>   se trata principalmente de informar, o declarar un hecho, suele ir en
>   indicativo.
>
> > "Si la información compartida se coloca normalmente al inicio de la
> >     oración, en una oración que comienza con 'el hecho de que' se supone
> >     que este hecho es ya conocido por los interlocutores, de modo que **lo
> >     que expresa la oración subordinada es un juicio de valor sobre ese
> >     hecho conocido**, por lo que la oración subordinada (V2) se emplea el
> >     modo subjuntivo".
>
> Esto suele confundir a los estudiantes de español ya que parece que
>   estamos hablando de hechos reales y no de un juicio sobre estos
>   hechos, pero si te fijas bien te darás cuenta de que en la mayoría de
>   los casos se ve que **la principal intención del hablante no es la de
>   informar o declarar un hecho, sino opinar sobre él**.

En tu ejemplo, *«las casualidades de que ella entrara»* tiene esta misma estructura.

El texto debe haberse referido ya a las supuestas casualidades, o bien (si es un texto literario, como parece serlo) el autor quiere mostrar con el uso del subjuntivo que estas casualidades eran habituales y que **no son el tema de la oración**: lo importante, el tema, es que las mismas *«habían quedado atrás»*.

Otra posibilidad es que la propia semántica de la palabra *casualidad* esté motivando el uso del subjuntivo. La situación parece ser ambigua, por lo cual el subjuntivo expresaría alguna duda o subjetividad. Imaginemos una situación donde no hay casualidad sino que la mujer está entrando siempre al mismo tiempo que el hombre se baña: en vez de *«las casualidades de que ella entrara...»* diríamos más bien algo así como *«las ocasiones en que ella entra**ba**...»*, con el verbo en indicativo en vez de subjuntivo.

Quizá ambas cosas explican el uso del subjuntivo. No es lo mismo hablar de *casualidades* (insinuando que no son casuales) que de *ocasiones* (donde es más claro que hay acciones deliberadas).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Pablo!